# TCPListener in golang: error when number of connections is above 60 / 260

Tags: go, connection, connection-pooling, pool, vertica

I am building TCP Proxy: `client` <-> `proxy` <-> `Vertica`
I have a `net.TCPListener`, which takes incoming requests by `AcceptTCP()` and creating connections, then, making connection to destination socket by `net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, raddr)`. Looks like a bridge. Default proxy model.
Firstly, at first version, i have a trouble: if i have 59 parallel incoming request, everything is fine. But if i have one more (60), i have a trouble: 1-59 connections are OK, but 60 and newer are fault. I cant catch error properly. Looks like some socket unexpectedly closes
Secondly, i tried to set queue for listener. It helps me a lot: but if i have more than 258 requests, i get error again.

My question: is there any limit of connections in `net` package? May be it is system limitation?

For external info: Vertica running in docker container, hw/system: macbook, vertica limit connection pool: 5, but pool logic implemented into proxy. 
I also tried set "raw" proxy without pool logic (thats why i set queue for listener: i must not exceed threshold of Vertica User's pool), result is 258 requests..

**UPDATED: (05.04.2020)**
Looks like it is system limitations fault. Did I mention anywhere that I trying to run the whole system on one PC? 
So, what I had:

- 300 parallel processes as requests (making by multiprocessing.Pool
  Python) (300 sockets)
- Listener that creates 300 connections (once
  more 300 sockets)
- And series of rapidly creating/closing sockets in
  deep of proxy (according to queue and Vertica pool)

What I have now:

- 300 python requests making from another PC in my local network (on Windows)
- Proxy works fine
- But I have several errors on Windows PC, which creating requests to my proxy. Errors like low memory in "swap file".

I still need to make some stress test for proxy. Adding less memory for swap file didn't solve my problem on Windows PC. I will be grateful for any suggestions and ideas. Thanks!

Comment: The `net` package does not have a connection limit.  Many systems do have a limit.  Write the application to handle and report the errors returned from AcceptTCP, DialTCP and the net.Conn methods.  The errors will be useful in debugging the issue.

Comment: @CeriseLimón yeah looks like you are absolute right about systems limit. Question was updated a few secs ago.

Answer (score 0):

How does the proxy connect to Vertica?
There is by default a maximum of 50 ordinary mortal users to be connected to one Vertica node at any one time. The superuser "dbadmin" always has 5 connections in addition to that.

So if I try to connect 60 times as dbadmin, I get this on a default Vertica configuration:

```
Connection attempt failed: FATAL 4060:  New session rejected due to limit, already 55 sessions active
```

You can increase the Vertica config item `MaxClientSessions` from its default of 50 per node.

Command is : `ALTER NODE <_node_name_> SET MaxClientSessions = 100`, for example.

I suppose you are always connecting to the same Vertica node, and that you have set `ConnectionLoadBalancing` to `FALSE`. So you always connect to the same node, and soon reach the default maximum of 50.

Hope that's the reason found ....

Comment: Proxy just builds a bridge between Client and Vertica. User connect via vertica-python, jdbc, etc...
As i mentioned at end of my question, I have vertica limit connection = 5 for my user (not dbadmin), and purpose of my proxy is handling a lot of connection, managing connections and provide slots for clients. It's hard to explain, english is not my native, so there is example:

Proxy:
User limit: 5
Parallel connections to proxy: 100
All: passed
Without proxy only 5 will be passed, other will failed

Hope you got it